# Como percorrer todos os registros na tabela do banco de dados?

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, if

Boa tarde, galera!
Estou iniciando em PHP e já me veio um probleminha.
É o seguinte:

Preciso percorrer todos registros na tabela do banco, para poder validar se tal valor já existe.
Estou usando o Codeigniter e fiz o seguinte mais ou menos isso:

```
$sql = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tabela")->result;

foreach ($sql as $resultado) {
if ($resultado->valor == $this->input->post("valor")) {
    echo "Valor já existente";
} else {
    echo "Cadastro OK";
}
}
```

Desta maneira está validando somente o primeiro registro da tabela, ou seja, ele só pega o "valor" da primeira linha e mostra "Valor já existente". 
Mas caso o valor procurado esteja a partir do segundo registro, ele continua cadastrando. 
Grato desde já!

Comment: Em teoria seu código está certo. Acho que seria mais simples fazer essa comparação no sql do que no php, basicamente vc passa o 'valor' no where se não existir cadastra um novo, caso existe bloqueia o cadastro. Poderia colocar o código de verdade?

Answer (score 1):

Parece ser mais simples verificar se o valor já existe no banco do que usar o php para isso. Adicione um `WHERE` comparando o valor desejado, caso tenha algum retorno não efetua um insert, se o returno for false faz um insert.

```
$sql = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE campos = 'valor'")->result;

if(!$sql){
   //faz o insert nesse bloco
}else{
    echo 'esse valor já existe, escolha outro';
}
```